# Handling foreach or forloop with array values PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

## Output Array (The variable name is $r)

```
    Array
    (
    [Jan-14] => 7588793.52
    [Feb-14] => 9944970.87
    [Mar-14] => 8567790.20
    [Apr-14] => 
    [May-14] => 
    [Jun-14] => 
    [Jul-14] => 
    [Aug-14] => 
    [Sep-14] => 
    [Oct-14] => 
    [Nov-14] => 
    [Dec-14] => 
    )
```

What I have done so far is..

```
   while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $series1['data'][] = $r['Jan-14'];
    $series2['data'][] = $r['Feb-14'];
    .... it will go till Dec-14.......
    array_push($result,$series1);
    array_push($result,$series2);
    .... it will go till Dec-14.......
}
```

Expected Output:

The code should look something like this this (dynamic)

```
  while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        for($i=1;$i<=count($r);$i++){

        $series.$i['data'][] =  ??????????
        array_push($result,$series.$i);
        ..................

        }

}
```

Help me out. Don't talk about the db structure or normalization. The db was given by my client.

Thanks,
Kimz

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
$result = array();
foreach($r as $month => $value) {
    $result[] = array('data' => array($value));
}
```

Comment: could you please fine-tune and give me as per my wish. please ;)

Comment: If you want someone else to implement your code for you there are sites like freelancer.com and peopleperhour.com that might more suitable than stackoverflow.